# Cannot assign additional memory to Coldfusion JVM

Tags: coldfusion, jvm-arguments, jrun

Good Day,

I am running Coldfusion 8 MX on a Windows 2003 32bit server with 4gig of RAM (2gig is always free) but I am unable to assign much more than 550m to the JVM.

I had already submitted this question but it got too long and confusing with all of my edits. The closest I ever got to it starting was when I set the -Xmn, it ran for 10 minutes before crashing. After crashing, it would not start with 1024m again, even with those same args.

These crash logs are for Java 1.6.0_38. I have tried with Java 5 and it gives the same result. I cannot even get CF8 to start with Java 7 (This is a separate issue).

I need to assign more RAM to the JVM so that CF doesn't keep crashing under heavy load, so any insight into this behaviour would be appreciated.

Java Args are:

```
java.args=-server -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -Xmn200m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Xloggc:{application.home}/../logs/CFGC/CFGC.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home}/../ -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/../lib
```

Crash Log #1 (The server ran for 10 minutes before producing this):

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7c82a5c4, pid=4604, tid=4760
#
# JRE version: 6.0_38-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.13-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x2a5c4]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x5c4f0400):  JavaThread "jrpp-2" [_thread_in_native, id=4760, stack(0x638d0000,0x639d0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x680bd710, EBX=0x003e0000, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x639cc950, EBP=0x639cc95c, ESI=0x680bd708, EDI=0x680b56f8
EIP=0x7c82a5c4, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x639cc950)
0x639cc950:   003e0000 680b56f8 00000000 639cca44
0x639cc960:   7c82a69b 003e0000 00000000 639cca24
0x639cc970:   00000000 00000057 680b5700 00008004
0x639cc980:   04c0a470 7c827b79 71b219d6 000018a4
0x639cc990:   00000001 639cc9ac 000018a4 00000103
0x639cc9a0:   00000103 639cc9c0 7c826e39 ffb3b4c0
0x639cc9b0:   ffffffff 0014dfa8 00000000 00000000
0x639cc9c0:   639cca38 580d0000 000018a4 00002020 

Instructions: (pc=0x7c82a5c4)
0x7c82a5a4:   85 db a6 02 00 8a 46 05 24 10 a8 10 88 47 05 0f
0x7c82a5b4:   85 02 0f 00 00 8b 4e 0c 8d 46 08 8b 10 89 4d 0c
0x7c82a5c4:   8b 09 3b 4a 04 89 55 14 0f 85 f5 72 01 00 3b c8
0x7c82a5d4:   0f 85 ed 72 01 00 56 53 e8 17 fa ff ff 8b 45 14 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x680bd710 is an unknown value
EBX=0x003e0000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x639cc950 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x5c4f0400
EBP=0x639cc95c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x5c4f0400
ESI=0x680bd708 is an unknown value
EDI=0x680b56f8 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x638d0000,0x639d0000],  sp=0x639cc950,  free space=1010k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2a5c4]  wcslen+0x1d6
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2a69b]  wcslen+0x2ad
C  [MSVCR71.dll+0x218a]  free+0x39
C  [net.dll+0x711f]  Java_java_net_SocketInputStream_socketRead0+0x1c6
j  java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BIII)I+0

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BIII)I+0
J  macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerByteOrderedDataReader.makeMoreDataAvailable()V
j  macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerByteOrderedDataReader.receive()V+14
j  macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRPCRequest.submitRequest(Lmacromedia/jdbc/sqlserver/SQLServerImplStatement;)V+132
j  macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRPCNonCursorExecuteRequest.submitPrepExec(Lmacromedia/jdbc/sqlserver/SQLServerImplStatement;Lmacromedia/jdbc/base/BaseWarnings;)V+26
j  macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRPCExecuteRequest.doPrepExec(Lmacromedia/jdbc/sqlserver/SQLServerImplStatement;Lmacromedia/jdbc/base/BaseWarnings;)V+29
j  macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRPCExecuteRequest.execute(Lmacromedia/jdbc/sqlserver/SQLServerImplStatement;Lmacromedia/jdbc/base/BaseWarnings;)V+339
j  macromedia.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerImplStatement.execute()V+468
j  macromedia.jdbc.base.BaseStatement.commonExecute()V+40
j  macromedia.jdbc.base.BaseStatement.executeInternal()Z+5
j  macromedia.jdbc.base.BasePreparedStatement.execute()Z+42
j  macromedia.jdbc.base.BasePreparedStatementPoolable.execute()Z+4
j  coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Ljava/sql/Connection;Ljava/lang/String;Lcoldfusion/sql/ParameterList;Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;[IIIZZ)Lcoldfusion/sql/Table;+507
j  coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Ljava/sql/Connection;Ljava/lang/String;Lcoldfusion/sql/ParameterList;Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;[ILcoldfusion/sql/DataSourceDef;)Lcoldfusion/sql/Table;+181
j  coldfusion.sql.Executive.executeQuery(Ljava/sql/Connection;Ljava/lang/String;Lcoldfusion/sql/ParameterList;Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;[ILjava/lang/Object;)Lcoldfusion/sql/Table;+61
j  coldfusion.sql.SqlImpl.execute(Z)Lcoldfusion/sql/Table;+138
j  coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.executeQuery(Z)Lcoldfusion/sql/Table;+5
j  coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag.doEndTag()I+65
j  cfTransferGateway2ecfc585582040$funcLISTBYPROPERTYMAP.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+2719
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CfJspPage;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfSQLManager2ecfc937842696$funcLISTBYPROPERTYMAP.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+450
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+26
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CfJspPage;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+58
j  cfTransfer2ecfc1333771829$funcREADBYPROPERTYMAP.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+278
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CfJspPage;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfUserService2ecfc1575820687$funcGETUSERBYPROPERTYMAP.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+116
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CfJspPage;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfCardListener2ecfc1071855549$funcGETCARD.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+333
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+26
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CfJspPage;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/lang/Object;+58
j  coldfusion.tagext.lang.InvokeTag.doEndTag()I+176
j  cfEventInvoker2ecfc577457096$funcINVOKELISTENER.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+412
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CfJspPage;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfNotifyCommand2ecfc1810625261$funcEXECUTE.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+295
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CfJspPage;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfEventHandler2ecfc451386063$funcHANDLEEVENT.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+322
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CfJspPage;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfRequestHandler2ecfc128659239$funcHANDLEEVENT.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+862
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfRequestHandler2ecfc128659239$funcHANDLENEXTEVENT.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+181
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfRequestHandler2ecfc128659239$funcPROCESSEVENTS.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+390
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfRequestHandler2ecfc128659239$funcHANDLEREQUEST.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+1738
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CfJspPage;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfmach2dii2ecfc392524582$funcHANDLEREQUEST.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+1653
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  cfApplication2ecfc1704547219$funcONREQUESTSTART.runFunction(Lcoldfusion/runtime/LocalScope;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CFPage;Lcoldfusion/runtime/ArgumentCollection;)Ljava/lang/Object;+829
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;Lcoldfusion/runtime/CfJspPage;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Z+28
j  coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequestStart([Ljava/lang/Object;Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)Z+5
j  coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+676
j  coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+56
j  coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+12
j  coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+124
j  coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+13
j  coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+5
j  coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+35
j  coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+120
j  coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+13
j  coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+5
j  coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(Lcoldfusion/filter/FusionContext;)V+82
j  coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+114
j  coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+30
j  jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+53
j  com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doHttpServletRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+468
j  com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFusionRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+262
j  com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+45
j  com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+39
j  jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+80
j  coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+9
j  coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+25
j  jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+80
j  jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+3
j  jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;Ljrun/servlet/InvokerChain;)V+183
j  jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+55
j  jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(Ljrun/servlet/ServletConnection;)V+249
j  jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(Ljrun/servlet/ServletConnection;)V+74
j  jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+24
j  jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+113
j  jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+16
j  jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+47
j  jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run()V+24
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
[I removed this section due to StackOverflow question size limits. Please let me know if you need to see this]

Other Threads:
0x56879000 VMThread [stack: 0x566d0000,0x567d0000] [id=5156]
0x568af000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x57260000,0x57360000] [id=3788]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
par new generation   total 184320K, used 34086K [0x039d0000, 0x101d0000, 0x101d0000)
eden space 163840K,  11% used [0x039d0000, 0x04cc5c60, 0x0d9d0000)
from space 20480K,  71% used [0x0edd0000, 0x0fc23e68, 0x101d0000)
to   space 20480K,   0% used [0x0d9d0000, 0x0d9d0000, 0x0edd0000)
concurrent mark-sweep generation total 843776K, used 325395K [0x101d0000, 0x439d0000, 0x439d0000)
concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 262144K, used 146524K [0x439d0000, 0x539d0000, 0x539d0000)

Code Cache  [0x00710000, 0x010f8000, 0x03710000)
total_blobs=2699 nmethods=2465 adapters=187 free_code_cache=40016832 largest_free_block=17152

Dynamic libraries:
[I removed this section due to StackOverflow question size limits. Please let me know if you need to see this]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -Xmn200m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Xloggc:C:\ColdFusion8\runtime/../logs/CFGC/CFGC.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dcoldfusion.rootDir=C:\ColdFusion8\runtime/../ -Dcoldfusion.libPath=C:\ColdFusion8\runtime/../lib -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djmx.invoke.getters=true 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\..\lib;C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\..\jintegra\bin;C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\..\jintegra\bin\international;C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Server;C:\ColdFusion8\verity\k2\_nti40\bin;C:\CFusionMX7\verity\k2\_nti40\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\PROGRA~1\NcFTP;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;D:\StrawberryPerl\c\bin;D:\StrawberryPerl\perl\site\bin;D:\StrawberryPerl\perl\bin;D:\php\ext;
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2003 family Build 3790 Service Pack 2

CPU:total 2 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 3919344k(2146400k free), swap 7963284k(5585376k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.13-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_38-b05), built on Nov 14 2012 01:50:25 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Wed Feb 06 17:21:55 2013
elapsed time: 401 seconds
```

Crash Log #2 (Right after it crashed I attempted to restart the CF Service with the same configuration, but it would not even start, and produced this error):

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7c8194cd, pid=6020, tid=5608
#
# JRE version: 6.0_38-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.13-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x194cd]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x568a2c00):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5608, stack(0x57060000,0x57160000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x0000e010

Registers:
EAX=0x5b644638, EBX=0x5a9f0000, ECX=0x5b652658, EDX=0x0000e010
ESP=0x5715e534, EBP=0x5715e56c, ESI=0x003e0000, EDI=0x5b652650
EIP=0x7c8194cd, EFLAGS=0x00010283

Top of Stack: (sp=0x5715e534)
0x5715e534:   5b652650 5b652658 5b652650 580d0000
0x5715e544:   00000000 5b673000 00000000 567d0140
0x5715e554:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000136
0x5715e564:   00000000 00000000 5715e590 7c81727a
0x5715e574:   5b653000 00020000 00000136 00001000
0x5715e584:   5b652650 003e0000 00000071 5715e7b8
0x5715e594:   7c82b460 003e0000 00007ff4 00007ff4
0x5715e5a4:   579f2508 7c86a7b2 00000000 5715e5d4 

Instructions: (pc=0x7c8194cd)
0x7c8194ad:   ff ff 0f b7 c8 8d 84 ce 78 01 00 00 39 00 0f 84
0x7c8194bd:   1d 55 ff ff 8b 50 04 8d 4f 08 89 01 89 51 04 57
0x7c8194cd:   89 0a 56 89 48 04 e8 5d 0f 01 00 66 83 7d fc 00
0x7c8194dd:   0f 85 0b 73 ff ff 8b 45 ec 85 c0 0f 85 8a 2d ff 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x5b644638 is an unknown value
EBX=0x5a9f0000 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x57608400
ECX=0x5b652658 is an unknown value
EDX=0x0000e010 is an unknown value
ESP=0x5715e534 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x568a2c00
EBP=0x5715e56c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x568a2c00
ESI=0x003e0000 is an unknown value
EDI=0x5b652650 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x57060000,0x57160000],  sp=0x5715e534,  free space=1017k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntdll.dll+0x194cd]  RtlFreeThreadActivationContextStack+0x418
C  [ntdll.dll+0x1727a]  towlower+0xb1
C  [ntdll.dll+0x2b460]  wcscpy+0x175
C  [MSVCR71.dll+0x16b3]  _crtLCMapStringA+0x305
C  [MSVCR71.dll+0x16db]  _crtLCMapStringA+0x32d
V  [jvm.dll+0x5edd3]
V  [jvm.dll+0x5eff2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x5f273]
V  [jvm.dll+0x27ed7e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x27c263]
V  [jvm.dll+0x259bf9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2600a3]
V  [jvm.dll+0x261382]
V  [jvm.dll+0x24fa4a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4882d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x493bf]
V  [jvm.dll+0x12e8a4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x15719c]
C  [MSVCR71.dll+0x9565]  endthreadex+0xa0
C  [kernel32.dll+0x2482f]  GetModuleHandleA+0xdf


Current CompileTask:
C2:   4520  97      java.util.Arrays.mergeSort([Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;IIILjava/util/Comparator;)V (235 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
[I removed this section due to StackOverflow question size limits. Please let me know if you need to see this]

Other Threads:
0x56879000 VMThread [stack: 0x566d0000,0x567d0000] [id=320]
0x568a6c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x57260000,0x57360000] [id=5852]

VM state:synchronizing (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x003e61c8] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x56879000

Heap
par new generation   total 184320K, used 37692K [0x039d0000, 0x101d0000, 0x101d0000)
eden space 163840K,  23% used [0x039d0000, 0x05e9f248, 0x0d9d0000)
from space 20480K,   0% used [0x0d9d0000, 0x0d9d0000, 0x0edd0000)
to   space 20480K,   0% used [0x0edd0000, 0x0edd0000, 0x101d0000)
concurrent mark-sweep generation total 843776K, used 1673K [0x101d0000, 0x439d0000, 0x439d0000)
concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 262144K, used 12535K [0x439d0000, 0x539d0000, 0x539d0000)

Code Cache  [0x00710000, 0x00950000, 0x03710000)
total_blobs=244 nmethods=121 adapters=77 free_code_cache=49693952 largest_free_block=21888

Dynamic libraries:
[I removed this section due to StackOverflow question size limits. Please let me know if you need to see this]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -Xmn200m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Xloggc:C:\ColdFusion8\runtime/../logs/CFGC/CFGC.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dcoldfusion.rootDir=C:\ColdFusion8\runtime/../ -Dcoldfusion.libPath=C:\ColdFusion8\runtime/../lib -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djmx.invoke.getters=true 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\..\lib;C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\..\jintegra\bin;C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\..\jintegra\bin\international;C:\Program Files\CollabNet Subversion Server;C:\ColdFusion8\verity\k2\_nti40\bin;C:\CFusionMX7\verity\k2\_nti40\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\PROGRA~1\NcFTP;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;D:\StrawberryPerl\c\bin;D:\StrawberryPerl\perl\site\bin;D:\StrawberryPerl\perl\bin;D:\php\ext;
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2003 family Build 3790 Service Pack 2

CPU:total 2 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 3919344k(2858352k free), swap 7963284k(5630528k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (20.13-b02) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_38-b05), built on Nov 14 2012 01:50:25 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Wed Feb 06 17:22:00 2013
elapsed time: 4 seconds
```

Comment: This is probably off-topic here and should be asked on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Someone mentioned that last time and the response was "That site is undermanned by Coldfusion people". I'm just hoping for an answer, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running on a 32-bit VM, which imposes some limits on how large the Heap can be. I'm not the world's best authority on this, so you may need to do further googling to confirm/clarify some of these points.

You only have a 2 Gig memory limit per process, so you have a number of things to fit into there :

- Your Heap. That's 1 gig in the example above
- Your Perm gen (that' not held in the heap I believe). That's 256 meg.
- Stack memory: Each thread has a stack, which is at least a meg in the example above. Multiply the number of threads by 1 meg and add that to the 1.25 gig above.
- Native Java code. The code and native memory of the JVM need to be loaded or mapped into the memory space.
- Other DLLs such as Windows functionality (ntdll.dll and MSVCR71.dll) and also I believe antivirus and various other cruft can get mapped in.

I believe  that you can get memory allocation problems if the DLLs are mapped into memory locations all over your 2 Gig space, you get a kind of fragmentation where there's no large contigous block of memory available.

Count the number of threads active (proabaly the bit you had to snip from the dumps above) and see how much of dent that puts into your memory. Our application uses -Xss256k to reduce the thread stack size to 256k and we've tested this at scale and at load and it works well for our application, but you'll want to test your own app.

After the crash when CF won't start at all, will it start with a lower -Xmx setting?

Try using the VMMap.exe tool from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533). It'll show you more than you ever wanted to know about what your process is doing. ProcMon is also very useful for higher-level process info.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd share my final solution with you all.

I'll spare you the boring details of how I reached this solution. Suffices to say, the best advice I received was "Find out exactly what the problem is first".

I ended up installing [JRockit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/jrockit/downloads/index.html) as a means of identifying what pieces of code are chewing up the most RAM.

In the process of this, it was necessary to change the JRE that Coldfusion uses, to the JRockit internal one.

```
#java.home=D:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre
java.home=D:/Program Files/Java/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_37-R28.2.5-4.1.0/jre
```

I believe that this JRE is made by BEA as opposed to SUN? Don't quote me on that. But I needed to change my java args as follows:

```
java.args=-server -Xmx1200m -Xms1200m -Xns300m -Xgc:singlecon -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home}/../ -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/../lib -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=53578 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

I've opened up a random port that JRockit can use to profile the JVM Heap usage. It's pointed me in the direction of several pieces of code, that I would never have thought were problematic.

However, I have also been tinkering with the RAM settings, and found that 1200m seems to be working quite alright.

Lesson learned: Not all JRE's were created equal.

Comment: Nice one, glad you got it sorted. Thanks for taking the time to write up your solution too.